# Literature on imposing boundary conditions on the method of characteristics solution to PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, characteristics

I am currently studying the method of characteristics. So far I understand what I read in literature. The problem is that I didn't find a good explanation for imposing boundary conditions anywhere. Also, in the textbook problems, only the initial conditions are given. Please recommend me some literature where I can study how to impose boundary conditions on the solutions obtained using this method. A hyperlink to the literature would be of great help.